# Loop to transform JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to write a JavaScript loop to transform my JavaScript object from this,

```
var d = {
      "time_completed": 1420199657,
      "xid": "-dqAeAEjGxCDcjqrxHsraER3yWqew4xS",
      "title": "for 8h 46m",
      "time_created": 1420167382,
      "time_updated": 1420200033,
      "details": {
        "body": 0,
        "sound": 12598,
        "tz": "America/Chicago",
        "awakenings": 0,
        "light": 18970,
        "mind": 0,
        "asleep_time": 1420168079,
        "awake_time": 1420199400,
        "awake": 707,
        "rem": 0,
        "duration": 32275,
        "smart_alarm_fire": 1420199640,
        "quality": 100,
        "sunset": 0,
        "sunrise": 0
      },
      "date": 20150102,
      "shared": true,
      "snapshot_image": "/nudge/image/e/1420200033/-dqAeAEjGxCDcjqrxHsraER3yWqew4xS/MSh0lOvjHDY.png",
      "sub_type": 0
    };
```

to this,

```
var d = {"sleep":[
  {"time_completed":"time_completed"},
  {"xid":"xid"},
  {"title":"title"},
  {"time_created":"time_created"},
  {"time_updated":"time_updated"},
  {"details": [
    {"body":"body"},
    {"sound":"sound"},
    {"tz":"tz"},
    {"awakenings":"awakenings"},
    {"light":"light"},
    {"mind":"mind"},
    {"asleep_time":"asleep_time"},
    {"awake_time":"awake_time"},
    {"awake":"awake"},
    {"rem":"rem"},
    {"duration":"duration"},
    {"smart_alarm_fire":"smart_alarm_fire"},
    {"quality":"quality"},
    {"sunset":"sunset"},
    {"sunrise":"sunrise"}
  ]},
  {"date":"date"},
  {"shared":"shared"},
  {"snapshot_image":"snapshot_image"},
  {"sub_type":"sub_type"}
]};
```

The `d` object won't always have the same elements (keys) or depth (children). So I'm trying to come up with a simple loop to extract the structure (keys and children) of the JavaScript object. Can someone offer me a solution?

Comment: Have you tried something already? Show us what did you do so far to achieve your goal.

Comment: Why is that you want to transform your object like that?

Comment: There's no JSON here. It's a plain old JavaScript object.

Comment: So I can illustrate the changing schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.keys() and recursion to iterate through your (nested) object properties, and Array.prototype.map() to convert it:

```
function mapKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj[key] = (typeof obj[key] === 'object') ? mapKeys(obj[key]) : key;
        return newObj;
    });
}

var result = {
    sleep: mapKeys(d)
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I really don't like the idea of spoon-fed code.

Comment: It depends. Somebody could copy-paste it, somebody could learn something by analyzing the code.

Comment: That's indeed a theoretical possibility, although the OP's inability to write a for-loop bodes poorly for him learning something from a solution that uses `Object.keys`, higher-order functions like `map`, and the ternary operator. I'm just wondering if SO's fate is going to be to continue to be people putting up questions they have no idea how to solve and other people writing code for them.

Comment: The accepted answer is a much more elegant solution than my verbose nested for loops. I learn a great deal from how others think and approach problems. @madox2 is clearly way more experienced than I am and his offer of novel methods I may not have considered, is valuable to a novice like me.

Comment: Is the bias helpful? Or are you seeking assurance I'm not just being lazy? Either way, I got a great answer and @madox2 presumably got the satisfaction of helping out a novice and some modest rep points for his time. I commend him for taking a min to help, rather than telling me to "google it" or lamenting the fate of SO.

Comment: @Colin, the problem, with all due respect, and congratulations on finding your answer, and thanks to madox2 for helping out here, is that posting to SO every time you don't know how to code something is not a scalable approach. People need to learn to solve problems by themselves, and the techniques to do so (of which Googling is very much one).

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
var transformed = {};

function transform(obj){
    var arr = [], prop, inner_obj;
    for(prop in obj){
        inner_obj = {};
        inner_obj[prop] = (typeof obj[prop] === 'object')? transform(obj[prop]) : obj[prop];
        arr.push(inner_obj);
    }
    return arr;
}

transformed['sleep'] = transform(d);
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write down in English what you want to do. It might look something like this:

1. Create a new array to hold the result.
2. Loop through all the properties of the object.
3. For each property, make a little object whose only key-value pair has both key and value having the property name. Add this little object to the new array.
4. Except, if the property has an object as its value, repeat this whole process for the sub-object.
5. Create a result object with a single `sleep` property with the new array as its value.

Now, you have to figure out how to do each step. For instance, for the second step, you'll need to know how to find all the properties of an object. Do you know how to do that? You could Google for "get all properties of a javascript object". You'll find there's something called `Object.keys()`. Then, you need to loop over those keys. If you don't know how to do that, there's a good new tutorial that just went up [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript). It would be a good idea to read through that.

How do I add a key-value pair to an object? That's very basic, and also covered in the tutorial: `new_object[key] = key`.

Since step 4 is a little bit harder, skip it in your first iteration, and get your program working with only a single level of nesting.

If you run into trouble while doing this, you will need to **debug** your program. There's a good tutorial on that topic [here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Continue process for the remaining steps, until you have a functioning JS program.